# How to update python on Azure Redhat Linux VM?

Tags: python, linux, azure, virtual-machine

I created an Azure Redhat Linux VM that came pre-installed with python 2.7.5. I need to update it to the latest version so I can then install databricks CLI on it to access DBFS. Need help on how to do this, please.

Tried:

```
$ sudo yum update python
```

Result:

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos
No packages marked for update
```

I need at least 2.7.9 version of python to be able to install databricks CLI.
I don't have an on-prem Linux server. Only have Windows and don't have admin access to install python on PowerShell.

Comment: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/08/13/install-python3-rhel/

Comment: You have to be very careful updating the system installed python on Linux.  There are many system utilities that use python and you could break them if you changed the installed version.  Better to install your version locally.

Comment: To elaborate on @cdarke's great comment; consider using something like conda https://conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html or other means of creating a virtual environment for your project that doesn't interfere with the system python. Otherwise you may find yourself in a world of pain, lots of the tooling around package management is written in python, so tampering with that is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the default Python version of a Linux distribution is depended on the Linux distribution version. So if you created the latest version of RedHat Linux on Azure VM, you can upgrade the default Python 2 version via the steps below.

1. Check whether exists an upgrade version of Python you want via `yum info python` or `yum list python`.
2. If there is an upgrade version, you can upgrade it via `yum -y upgrade python` or `yum -y update python`.

For older Linux distribution, there is an upper limit version of Python, such as `2.7.5` for Python 2 on your current RedHat Linux VM I guess. So you could not simply upgrade it via the system package manager `yum` to install an upper version from default package repository. Then, we need to download the source code of a specified version of Python to compile and install on the current environment.

There is a blog [`How to Install or Upgrade Python in Linux Systems`](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2016/10/install-python-centos-ubuntu-linux.html) introduces how to do.

Here is my steps to install Python 2.7.9.

1. Make sure there is compiler tool kits `gcc` & `g++` installed in your current environment. To check via `gcc -v` and `g++ -v`. To install via `yum -y install gcc gcc-c++` and other dependencies like `zlib`, `zlib-dev`, `openssl`, `openssl-dev`, `ncurses-libs`, `readline-devel`, `sqlite-devel`, `bzip2-devel`, `gdbm-devel`, `libdbi-devel`, and so on.
2. Download the source code package from the offical Python FTP via `$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.9/Python-2.7.9.tgz`.
3. Decompress it via `tar -zxvf Python-2.7.9.tgz`.
4. `cd Python-2.7.9`.

If you just want to use Python 2.7.9 temporarily, the next steps are as below.

5. `./configure && make`
6. To configure the `PATH` environment variable via `export PATH=$HOME/<the parent path>/Python-2.7.9/:$PATH`
7. Then, you can use Python 2.7.9 in the current Shell session.

If you want to install Python 2.7.9 into `/usr/local` and not break the current default Python version to avoid the possible system crash issue, the next steps as as below.

5. `./configure --prefix=/usr/local`
6. `make && sudo make altinstall`
7. Then, you can use Python 2.7.9 via `python2.7`. You can check all Python version via `python -V`, `python2 -V` and `python2.7 -V`.

Hope it helps.